# How to add record to Reference List for Record Type using CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a two simple Record Types: `Artwork` and `Artist`. `Artwork` as a child may belong to **one** `Artist`, however one `Artist` may have multiply artworks.

Below are the screenshots related to mentioned Record Types.

[image]
[image]

I can simply setup `artist` for `artwork` the following way:

```
let artistID = CKRecordID(recordName: "F297D690-888B-4B55-9FBD-27CAEF4BBD83")
let artworkID = CKRecordID(recordName: self.idTextField.text!)

self.container.publicCloudDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(artworkID, completionHandler: { artwork, error in

    if let artwork = artwork {

        artwork["artist"] = CKReference(recordID: artistID, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
        self.container.publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(artwork, completionHandler: { artwork, error in

             print("done")
        })
    }
})
```

But the question is:

**How to setup relationships in reversed relation? In other words how to add `artworkID` to the reference list of `artistID`?**

Apple says:

> ...to represent the one-to-many relationship from `Artist` to `Collection` in the object model, add a reference field to the `Collection` record.

But how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest answer I have found:

```
let artworkID = CKRecordID(recordName: self.idTextField.text!)
if let artist = artist, var artworks = artist["artworks"] as? [CKReference] {

    let reference = CKReference(recordID: artworkID, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
    if !artworks.contains(reference) {
        artworks.append(reference)
    }
    artist["artworks"] = artworks

    //here you can save your changes or do whatever it needs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problems can be found in the Apple documentation that says...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKReference_class/

It is permissible to create circular owning references for a set of records.

To save multiple records containing references between them, save the target records first or **save all the records in one operation using the same *CKModifyRecordsOperation* object**.

The code to setup a reference in CloudKit I sure you seen?

```
    let uniqReference = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let unqUUID = CKRecordID(recordName: uniqUUID)
    let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Blah", recordID: uniqUUID)
```

It says you need to save all your records @ the same time with a CKModifyOperation.

```
func saveLeCollection(theGlob:NSURL) {

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "Blah.com")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let uniqUUID = CKRecordID(recordName: uniqReference)
    let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Blah", recordID: uniqUUID)
    let whistleAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: theImage)
    newRecord["theImage"] = whistleAsset

    newRecord.setObject(uniqUUID, forKey: "theLink")

    var localChanges:[CKRecord] = []
    localChanges.append(newRecord)

    let saveRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: localChanges, recordIDsToDelete: records2Erase)
    saveRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .ChangedKeys
    saveRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock =  { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        // deal with conflicts
        // set completionHandler of wrapper operation if it's the case
    }
    saveRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            // deal with conflictsay
            // set completionHandler of wrapper operation if it's the case

            }
        }
    }

    saveRecordsOperation.qualityOfService = .Background
    publicDB.addOperation(saveRecordsOperation)
}
```

If I store the ArtistID in my artwork record, the same ID in every artwork record I have a many->one reference. And with my reference List I have one->many reference with my Artist record pointing to each artwork record.

Comment: Could you apply this example to my code from question? I think your answer is not clear, and suppose is out of this topic (not sure). The question is not about how to save changes (*one by one or all at time*) but how to establish **one to many** relationship?